# CSS Image Sprite Animations With steps() Function not working with my image

Tags: html, css, user-interface, animation

i used CSS step function ([link](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-image-sprite-animations-with-steps-function))

this example work fine but change my image that case it is not working perfect anyone guide me

mycode

```
@-webkit-keyframes wink {
from { background-position: 0px; }
to { background-position: -5963px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes wink {
from { background-position: 0px; }
to { background-position: -5963px; }
}

@keyframes wink {
from { background-position: 0px; }
to { background-position: -5963px; }
}

.hi {
 width: 205px;
 height: 241px;
  background-image: url("images/Street-background-13.png");
 margin: 0 auto;

 -webkit-animation: wink 6s steps(29, end) infinite;
 -moz-animation: wink 6s steps(29, end) infinite;
 animation: wink 6s steps(29, end) infinite;
```

**My Image link** [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r443O.png)

Comment: Check my snippet, your car is driving :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the background colour, and add vendor specific prefixes (oh and add a last curly brace to end your css definition for .hi), it works, check it out:

```css
        @-webkit-keyframes wink {
          from {
            background-position: 0px;
          }
          to {
            background-position: -5963px;
          }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes wink {
          from {
            background-position: 0px;
          }
          to {
            background-position: -5963px;
          }
        }

        @-o-keyframes wink {
          from {
            background-position: 0px;
          }
          to {
            background-position: -5963px;
          }
        }

        @keyframes wink {
          from {
            background-position: 0px;
          }
          to {
            background-position: -5963px;
          }
        }
        .hi {
          width: 205px;
          height: 241px;
          background-color: #000;
          background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/r443O.png");
          margin: 0 auto;
          -webkit-animation: wink 6s steps(29, end) infinite;
          -moz-animation: wink 6s steps(29, end) infinite;
          -o-animation: wink 6s steps(29, end) infinite;
          animation: wink 6s steps(29, end) infinite;
        }
```

```html
<div class="hi">

</div>
```